# Could not decrypt cipher text using aes 256 in gcm mode

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I have the following code:

```
int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *aad,
            int aad_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv,
            unsigned char *ciphertext, unsigned char *tag)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len=0, ciphertext_len=0;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the encryption operation. */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Set IV length if default 12 bytes (96 bits) is not appropriate */
    if(1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise key and IV */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors();

    /* Provide any AAD data. This can be called zero or more times as
     * required
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &len, aad, aad_len))
        handleErrors();

    /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    /* encrypt in block lengths of 16 bytes */
    while(ciphertext_len<=plaintext_len-16)
    {
        if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext+ciphertext_len, &len, plaintext+ciphertext_len, 16))
            handleErrors();
        ciphertext_len+=len;
    }
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext+ciphertext_len, &len, plaintext+ciphertext_len, plaintext_len-ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len+=len;

    /* Finalise the encryption. Normally ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage, but this does not occur in GCM mode
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + ciphertext_len, &len)) handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Get the tag */
    if(1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, tag))
        handleErrors();

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *aad,
            int aad_len, unsigned char *tag, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv,
            unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len=0, plaintext_len=0, ret;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the decryption operation. */
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Set IV length. Not necessary if this is 12 bytes (96 bits) */
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise key and IV */
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /* Provide any AAD data. This can be called zero or more times as
     * required
     */
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &len, aad, aad_len))
        handleErrors();

    /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    while(plaintext_len<=ciphertext_len-16)
    {
        if(1!=EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext+plaintext_len, &len, ciphertext+plaintext_len, 16))
            handleErrors();
        plaintext_len+=len;
    }
    if(1!=EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext+plaintext_len, &len, ciphertext+plaintext_len, ciphertext_len-plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len+=len;

    /* Set expected tag value. Works in OpenSSL 1.0.1d and later */
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, tag))
        handleErrors();

    /* Finalise the decryption. A positive return value indicates success,
     * anything else is a failure - the plaintext is not trustworthy.
     */
    ret = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + plaintext_len, &len);

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    if(ret > 0)
    {
        /* Success */
        plaintext_len += len;
        return plaintext_len;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Verify failed */
        return -1;
    }
}

void EncDecTest() {
    std::vector<char> cipherText(34, '0');

    std::string pt;
    pt.reserve(1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH);

    std::string aad = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    int k;

    std::string plaintext = "This is some dummy text to encrypt";
    std::string tag(16, '0');

    const unsigned char genKey[] = { 0xa6, 0x32, 0x56, 0xba, 0x2b, 0x74, 0xdb, 0x5e, 0xa5, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x14, 0x69, 0xfb, 0xf2, 0x75,
                                     0xba, 0x25, 0xd8, 0xca, 0xc6, 0xd7, 0x19, 0xa3, 0x06, 0xb8, 0x10, 0xd0, 0x2a, 0x02, 0xa7, 0xa1, 0 };

    const unsigned char iv[] = { 0xfd, 0xac, 0xc9, 0x0f, 0x36, 0x02, 0xf2, 0xbb, 0x03, 0x9b, 0x05, 0x67, 0 };

    k = encrypt((unsigned char*)plaintext.c_str(), plaintext.length(), (unsigned char *)aad.c_str(),
                aad.length(), (unsigned char*)genKey, (unsigned char*)iv,
                (unsigned char *)&cipherText[0], (unsigned char*)tag.c_str());

    k = decrypt((unsigned char *)&cipherText[0],
                k,
                (unsigned char *)aad.c_str(),
                aad.length(),
                (unsigned char*)tag.c_str(),
                (unsigned char*)genKey,
                (unsigned char*)iv,
                (unsigned char *)pt.c_str());

    if ( k > 0 ) {
        pt[k]='\0';
        printf("%s\n", pt.c_str());
    }
    else {
        printf("Unreliable Decryption, maybe the encrypted data was tampered\n");
    }
}
```

It uses openssl and works perfectly fine. I took this code from the github https://github.com/bawejakunal/AES-GCM-256. I wrote simple example to perform decryption with the same tag and cipher text that was generated in my **EncDecTest()** function. I have hard-coded it as a hex arrays. The code looks like this:

```
void simpleDecryptionTest() {
    int k;
    unsigned char pt[1024+EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH] = { 0 };

    std::string aad = "abcdefghijklmnop";

    const unsigned char genKey[] = { 0xa6, 0x32, 0x56, 0xba, 0x2b, 0x74, 0xdb, 0x5e, 0xa5, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x14, 0x69, 0xfb, 0xf2, 0x75,
                                     0xba, 0x25, 0xd8, 0xca, 0xc6, 0xd7, 0x19, 0xa3, 0x06, 0xb8, 0x10, 0xd0, 0x2a, 0x02, 0xa7, 0xa1, 0 };
    const unsigned char iv[] = { 0xfd, 0xac, 0xc9, 0x0f, 0x36, 0x02, 0xf2, 0xbb, 0x03, 0x9b, 0x05, 0x67, 0 };

    unsigned char cipher[] = { 0xAB, 0x04, 0xD2, 0x67, 0xF7, 0xA4, 0x81, 0xFC, 0x7A, 0x8B, 0x00,
                               0x50, 0xC0, 0x57, 0xA4, 0xE3, 0x1D, 0x0E, 0x53, 0xA5, 0xE9,
                               0x31, 0x5D, 0xE0, 0xDC, 0x1A, 0x5E, 0x6A, 0xCE, 0x9F, 0xCE, 0x86, 0xB4, 0xE5, 0 };

    unsigned char tagHard[] = { 0x7F, 0xA2, 0x24, 0x8B, 0xE2, 0x2A, 0x71, 0xC9, 0x07, 0xF8, 0x5C, 0xDC, 0x3C, 0xCD, 0x38, 0x8E, 0 };

    k = decrypt(cipher,
                34,
                (unsigned char *)aad.c_str(),
                aad.length(),
                (unsigned char*)tagHard,
                (unsigned char*)genKey,
                (unsigned char*)iv,
                pt);

    if ( k > 0 ) {
        pt[k] = '\0';
        printf("Message has been decrypted\n");
    }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that decryption fails. I have compared all the memory that goes to the input parameters to **decrypt()** function, they are 100% identical, but I don't understand why I am not able to perform decryption of it. I am appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IV

```
    const unsigned char iv[] = { 0xfd, 0xac, 0xc9, 0x0f, 0x36, 0x02, 0xf2, 0xbb, 0x03, 0x9b, 0x05, 0x67, 0 };
```

is 13 bytes.

But you're setting the length to 16 bytes with

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL)
```

Unless you *really* know what you're doing, you should use a 12-byte IV that's generated randomly when using AES/GCM.  And even if you know what you're doing, **NEVER** reuse any key/IV combination. See https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38d/final

So get rid of your calls to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL)`

Comment: I am not reusing key/IV combination, this was just for testing.

Comment: One thing I did not get is why do I need to get rid of EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl() calls? It's working for me when I replaced to 12.

Comment: @Oleg The default is 12.